# Writing to file using QT. Write data to already written file at particular points

Tags: html, qt

I have an html file which is generated when I press a button in qt. I want to send some data at a specific point in the html file when I click senddata button. How can I put the specific point.
When I press submit, A.html is generated.
I have to insert data1, data2 and data3 at different time instances. 
These data should be inserted at some specific points in A.html file.

Ex. On clicking Submit, A.html is generated, below is the data in A.html
line1

line2

line3

On clicking sendData, the file should look like
 A.html
line1
data3
line2
data1
line3
data2

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTML file is like a XML file. You can use the QtXml module to insert child nodes at a specific timestamp.

You should start reading http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xml-dom-tml.html and look at the examples http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-xml.html

Once you have grasp the concept, you can ask a more specific question on SO. Good luck.