# QTabWidget tab not showing up

Tags: qt, qtgui, qtabwidget

I am using multiple `QTabWidget`s tabs. I need the second tab to show up when a particular function is called.

The current tab page being 1, the tab page 2 should come up and tab page 1 should hide behind. I searched and tried a lot but with no avail.

I tried this too

```
ui->myTab->myTabPage2->show();
```

Used this in a function while the tab number 1 is showing visible and the tabPage2 being hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
QTabWidget::setCurrentIndex(int tabnumber);
```

Or

```
QTabWidget::setCurrentWidget(QWidget* yourwidget);
```

Here is the doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabwidget.html

Comment: @Kikohs Can you also help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559171/writing-to-file-using-qt-wtite-data-to-already-written-file-at-particular-point    ... Thanks!